# sql and c# gives different sum for same data

Tags: c#, sql

I have a a table myTable with field total `decimal(18,3)` in `SQl server 2008 R2` , if I `sum(total)` for all records in SQL it gives me a number , say '220150.36' however when I rterieve the same records to `c# (VS 2010)` and I sum up the same field total (but now in C#) , it gives me a different number '220396' , the records are retrieved to `datatable` and the total field in this datatable is of type decimal.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Culture` issue. Check out decimal seprator of the value present in DB, in your case seems it is `,`.

Try something like this:

```
double.Parse(val, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

For France, decimal separator is `,` so the value will be handled correctly and you will get correct sum result.